# AddToRole fails with a + sign in the username?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authentication

I am using this to add a newly created user, to  role:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.UserRole);
```

In my solution username = email.

I have discovered, when the username/email contains a sign (+, - or anything like that), it will not add the user to a role. The error i get is "`User name x is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.`".
The user gets added succesfully, it is just the AddToRole, that fails.

But i cannot figure out why.

`AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames` is set to false, in IdentityConfig.cs

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the user is being added to the database?

Comment: Yes, 100%. I can see the user in the user table and login also

Comment: That's strange. The error message you are getting makes no sense then. Because `AddToRole` doesn't do anything but storing the _UserId_ and the _RoleId_. At this point it has nothing to do with usernames anymore.

Comment: I found this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002798/addtorole-returns-user-name-can-only-contain-letters-or-digits-only-when-use but i cannot see how i can adapt it to my code

Comment: Where did you set the `AllowAlphanumericUserNames` part? I just know it in combination with ASP.NET MVC and there it is store in a funtion called _Create_ in _IdentityConfig_. It looks like this: `...var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ConnectionString>())); manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false, RequireUniqueEmail = true}`...

Comment: That exact code, is what i have in my IdentyConfig.cs file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible solutions I can think of.

1.) Follow [the solution you linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27021067/4498937) by editing your code sample to this:

```
var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.UserRole);
```

2.) Re-create the `UserValidator` in your `userManager` and attempt to `AddToRole` again:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(userManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false, RequireUniqueEmail = true };
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.UserRole);
```

Comment: What should i input in 'manager': userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<IdentityUser>(manager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false, RequireUniqueEmail = true }; ? "userManager" gives me .. Cannot Convert.. ApplicationUser to.. EntityFramework.IdendityUser

Comment: @brother edited some of it, sorry for the mixed up code

Comment: Sorry, but i get the same error? :( When i try your solution 1, i get "The name Context does not excist in the current context"?

Comment: @brother try solution 2 again

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much for your answer and patience :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you are creating a new instance of *UserManager* and not using the one if the *IdentityConfig* . Try to set 
`userManager.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;` after the line `var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);` of your code

Answer (score 0):

Make AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames as false by adding the code below and this works out.

```
  userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User>(userManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false
        };
```